# Recurrence Relation with two variables and boundary conditions

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I try to express the following recurrence relation in Mathematica:

I am very sorry but for any reason I am not allowed to embed math code here...

\begin{align*}
    x_{1,t} &= \frac{1}{2} x_{1,t-1} + \frac{1}{2} x_{2,t-1} \\
    x_{i,t} &= \frac{1}{2} x_{i-1,t-1} + \frac{1}{2} x_{i+1,t-1} & 1 < i < n \\
    x_{n,t} &= \frac{1}{2} x_{n-1,t-1} + \frac{1}{2} x_{n,t-1}
    \end{align*}

This is my approach but it does not work. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks a lot!

```
RSolve[{x[i, t] == 1/2*x[i - 1, t - 1] + 1/2* x[i + 1, t - 1], 
    x[i, 0] == 1, x[1, t] = 1/2*x[1, t - 1] + 1/2*x[2, t - 1], 
    x[n, t] = 1 & 2*x[n, t - 1] + 1/2*x[n - 1, t - 1]}, x[1, n], x]
```

Comment: Your equations have to be adjusted: `RSolve[{x[i, t] == 1/2*x[i - 1, t - 1] + 1/2*x[i + 1, t - 1], 
  x[1, t] == 1/2*x[1, t - 1] + 1/2*x[2, t - 1], 
  x[n, t] == 1/2*x[n, t - 1] + 1/2*x[n - 1, t - 1]}, x[i, t], {i, t}]`  . Unfortunately MMA can't solve it...

Comment: :-( thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to explain first exactly what you are trying to do. It looks like some kind of finite-difference routine (which is built-in).

Although you write `x[i, 0] == 1`, since $1<i<n$ you also need to give the initial values for `x[0, 0]` and `x[n, 0]`.

Assuming an initial array of the form

```
start = Join[Join[{0}, ConstantArray[1, {10}]], {0}]
```

you can use `NestList` and `ListConvolve` to perform the iteration, e.g.

```
NestList[ListConvolve[{1/2, 1/2}, #, 1], start, 10]
```

And you can use options to `ListConvolve` to control the alignment and overhangs.